# Variables with Mpdf Php ( variable's value not showing up on pdf file)

Tags: php, mpdf

So im using **mpdf** as you see to output a pdf with some form's inserted data. I tried with one variable `dtnom` to see if it works, and sadly, it doesn't appear on the pdf. i only get the `h3` tag content appearing. i don't know what i am doing wrong. I checked the solutions existing here on **stackoverflow** (and i know there exist quite many) but nth helps so here i am asking my help. and btw i get no error so far.

THANKS!

```
<?php 
ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); 
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf([
    'mode' => 'utf-8',
    'debug' => true,
    'allow_output_buffering' => true
]);
$stylesheet = file_get_contents('../styles/pdf.css');
$dtnom= $_SESSION['nom']; 
$html = '<html>'.
'<body>'.
'<h3>BON DU DÉPLACEMENT</h3>'.
'<span>Nom : &nbps '.$dtnom.'</span>'.
'</body>'.
'</html>';
$mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet,1);
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html,2);
$mpdf->Output();
```

Comment: What is the ``` in last code !

Comment: @AbdAbughazaleh oh no dw abt that. it isnt in the actual code. it is just for displaying the code here on the question. :/

Comment: This looks ok and works correctly. Even if your $dtnom is empty it should at least show `Nom : &nbps` under the h3. Or if this is not in session it should error out. Try without css file, maybe styling is messing this up. Also which version of php?

Comment: @blahy Actually when i removed the css thing, it actually worked. ( PHP 7.4.8 ). So now the question became how can i add some css without ruining everything ..if you have any idea please

Comment: try by adding parts of it, first empty css file, then a css file with changing the styles for h3. see if this works and then add the rest of the rules. Maybe you have a rule there to style spans as white text? I dont know the contents of the css.

Comment: @blahy  ill figure out a way. Wish you a blessed day. Thank you